# Permutation of Stripes in Flag on conditions

Tags: python, algorithm, permutation

I need help with a strategy on how do I find the number of the ways to arrange three stripes of color White, Blue and Red in a flag on conditions:

1. Stripes of the same color cannot be placed next to each other.
2. A blue stripe must always be placed between a white and a red or between a red and a white one.

for n=3 (only three stripes can be in the flag), the output is 4

Here's the link to the problem for further.
http://acm.timus.ru/problem.aspx?space=1&num=1225

Comment: Can you explain how the example solution in the problem can have red-white-red and white-red-white given rule two? Am I missing something?

Comment: @MarkMeyer I assume rule 2 means a blue stripe must be placed so _if present_. It must not be placed between white-white or red-red.

Comment: @MichaelButscher yes that’s a reading that makes it work. Thanks.

Comment: @MarkMeyer for example, when n=3, the flags can have stripes as- WRW, RBW, WBR and RWR where R->Red, W->White, B->Blue

Comment: I'm confused. Why is my answer the only one out of four that addresses what the output is supposed to be? :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First generate all possible combinations of stripes:

```
import itertools
stripes = list(itertools.product('RBW',repeat=3))
print(stripes)
```

Output:

```
[('R', 'R', 'R'), ('R', 'R', 'B'), ('R', 'R', 'W'), ('R', 'B', 'R'), ('R', 'B', 'B'), ('R', 'B', 'W'), ('R', 'W', 'R'), ('R', 'W', 'B'), ('R', 'W', 'W'), ('B', 'R', 'R'), ('B', 'R', 'B'), ('B', 'R', 'W'), ('B', 'B', 'R'), ('B', 'B', 'B'), ('B', 'B', 'W'), ('B', 'W', 'R'), ('B', 'W', 'B'), ('B', 'W', 'W'), ('W', 'R', 'R'), ('W', 'R', 'B'), ('W', 'R', 'W'), ('W', 'B', 'R'), ('W', 'B', 'B'), ('W', 'B', 'W'), ('W', 'W', 'R'), ('W', 'W', 'B'), ('W', 'W', 'W')]
```

Then jettison that are not full-filling requirements, firstly: no 2 same color next to each other, let make function for checking that:

```
def no_two(x):
    return all([i[0]!=i[1] for i in zip(x[1:],x[:-1])])
```

Then use it following way:

```
stripes = [s for s in stripes if no_two(s)]
print(stripes)
```

Output:

```
[('R', 'B', 'R'), ('R', 'B', 'W'), ('R', 'W', 'R'), ('R', 'W', 'B'), ('B', 'R', 'B'), ('B', 'R', 'W'), ('B', 'W', 'R'), ('B', 'W', 'B'), ('W', 'R', 'B'), ('W', 'R', 'W'), ('W', 'B', 'R'), ('W', 'B', 'W')]
```

Then we need function to check if blue is always between white and red or red and white:

```
def blue_between(x):
    if x[0]=='B':
        return False
    if x[-1]=='B':
        return False
    for i in zip(x[:-2],x[1:-1],x[2:]):
        if i[1]=='B':
            if not ((i[0]=='R' and i[2]=='W') or (i[0]=='W' and i[2]=='R')):
                return False
    return True
```

And use it following way:

```
stripes = [s for s in stripes if blue_between(s)]
print(stripes)
```

Output:

```
[('R', 'B', 'W'), ('R', 'W', 'R'), ('W', 'R', 'W'), ('W', 'B', 'R')]
```

Note usage of `zip` and index slicing to get current strip and next or previous and next stripe.

Comment: Yay! Excellent, Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Using `itertools.product` for getting all possible combinations and `itertools.groupby` for checking if there isn't any stripes of same color next to each other:

```
from itertools import product, groupby

colors = [1, 2, 3]  # 1 - red, 2 - blue, 3 - white
n = 3

output = []
for c in product(colors, repeat=n):
    # do we have consecutive colors?
    if max(sum(1 for _ in g) for _, g in groupby(c)) > 1:
        continue
    # is blue color on any end?
    if c[0] == 2 or c[-1] == 2:
        continue
    # is blue color between same colors?
    if any(c[i-1] == c[i+1] for i, v in enumerate(c) if v==2):
        continue
    output.append(c)

from pprint import pprint
pprint(output, width=30)
```

Prints:

```
[(1, 2, 3),
 (1, 3, 1),
 (3, 1, 3),
 (3, 2, 1)]
```

Comment: Thanks. I'll check product and groupby in itertools

Answer (score 0):

You can use recursion with a generator:

```
def flags(d, c = []):
   if len(c) == 3:
      yield c
   else:
      for i in d:
         if (c and c[-1] != i and (True if i != 'B' else len(c) == 1) and ('B' not in c or i not in c)) or (not c and i != 'B'):
            yield from flags(d, c+[i])


print(list(flags(['R', 'W', 'B'])))
```

Output:

```
[['R', 'W', 'R'], ['R', 'B', 'W'], ['W', 'R', 'W'], ['W', 'B', 'R']]
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's one answer accepted by the online judge. Let `m(n, c)` represent the number of ways to decorate an n-stripe textile ending in colour `c`. Then

```
m(n, r) =
  // choose white
  m(n - 1, w) +
  // choosing blue, we skip n-1
  m(n - 2, w)

m(n, w) =
  // choose red
  m(n - 1, r) +
  // choosing blue, we skip n-1
  m(n - 2, r)
```

Python code, incorporating the learning:

```py
from sys import stdin, stdout

# https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/python-program-for-program-for-fibonacci-numbers-2
def fibonacci(n): 
    a = 0
    b = 1
    if n < 0: 
        print("Incorrect input") 
    elif n == 0: 
        return a 
    elif n == 1: 
        return b 
    else: 
        for i in range(2,n): 
            c = a + b 
            a = b 
            b = c 

        return b

n = int(stdin.read())
m = 2 * fibonacci(n + 1)
stdout.write("%s" % m)
```

Comment: What does the `1 +` part mean in the formulas?

Comment: @GZ0 a mistake. Thanks.